# How to automate the deployment of a lib with Maven (m2e plugin) to Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, maven, m2e

I'm trying to deploy from Eclipse to Tomcat using *m2e*. 
Thing is I'm using a connection pool and I need to deploy the MySql driver to the /apache/bin dir and the context.xml to the /apache/conf directory.

Does anyone know how to automate that on the maven deploy?

Comment: Can you all this stuff via a war file? If i recognise that well it does work that way. I'm not sure if this is possible via Tomcat manager etc. ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In eclipse, go to **ProjectProperties->DeploymentAssembly** Here you can define where the files need to go into the war package directories. When you deploy via eclipse, this DeploymentAssembly is considered. Hence by mapping here I suppose you can achieve it..